# can there be a negative number in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The solution to the equation (-2/k)*-4=-1 (k= -8) is a negative in the denominator. Is that allowed?
thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wch86.png)

Comment: Yes, negative numbers are allowed in denominators of fractions. I'm not exactly sure what the question is here, as the equation $k=-8$ seems a bit odd...can you expand a bit?

Comment: I tried to post an image of the equation but it's (-2/k)*-4=-1 Basically, is 1/-4 the same as -1/4?

Comment: @Rolomoto Please do look for directions on how to write mathematics properly in this site. It *seems* to be that the equation might be $$\left(-\frac2k\right)(-4)=-1\implies k=-8 ...$$

Answer (score 1):

Fractions are allowed to have negative numerators and/or denominators. Generally, for all $b\ne 0$, $$\frac {-a}{b}=\frac a{-b}=-\frac ab$$
It is apparent that the last notation is graphically more pleasant than the others.